# After creating models from existing database in .net core not able to get JSON result

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I create my models from an existing database by the following commands:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=MYPC90;Database=NS;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

After that I create an empty API controller by the following code:

```
    namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
    {
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly NSContext _context;

        public UsersController(NSContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUSers()
        {
            return _context.User.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

but when I run the program I receive the following error:

[image]

I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution.
Can anybody help me?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using dependency injection by injecting `NSContext` into the controller's constructor. So, you should register `NSContext` to `ServiceProvider`  in `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup.cs` class as follow:

```
services.AddDbContext<NSContext>();
```

Using this, on each request to your application an instance of `NSContext` will be instantiated and stored in `ServiceProvider`.